# How to quickly tell that a quadratic only has a single root?

Tags: quadratic-forms

Hello good math wizards,  I'm trying to figure out why the following equation has at most one root:

$$f (t) = \textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{x} + \textbf{x} \cdot t\textbf{y} + t\textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x} + t\textbf{y} \cdot t\textbf{y} = \left \| \textbf{x} \right \|^2
+ 2(\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y})t + \left \| \textbf{y} \right \|^2t^2$$

where $\textit{t}$ is a real number, $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ are fixed vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\textbf{y}\neq0$

The background of this question is that I am going through the text [here](http://cfsv.synechism.org/c1/sec12.pdf), and in the section about the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality the authors state "Hence f is a quadratic polynomial with at most one root."  However, I don't understand why this quadratic has at most one root.  Can someone help clarify why it should be immediately apparent that his equation has only one root?

Just FYI this isn't homework or anything; I'm just going through the text.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another way to write it is $f(t) = \lVert \mathbf{x} + t\cdot \mathbf{y}\rVert^2$. Can you see that $f$ has at most one (real) root in this form?

Comment: Wonderful, thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that
$$f(t) = ||\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{y}||^2$$
Thus $f$ can obviously only have one root, which would be $\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{y} = 0$.

Comment: And why has $\mathbf x+t\mathbf y=0$ only one root?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Because $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are fixed, thus $\mathbf{x} + t\mathbf{x}=0$ is a polynomial of degree $1$ and has at most one root (on a field of characteristic $0$, wit the assumption $\mathbf{y}\neq 0$).

Comment: Dear Daniel, $\textbf x+ t\textbf y $ is not a polynomial: a polynomial in $t$ is an element of $R[t]$ for some ring $R$. Which ring $R$ do you have in mind?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Ok, I expressed myself badly. It is a polynomial in every component, thus for every component we have at most one value of $t$, call it $t_i$, for which $x_i + t_iy_i = 0$. Then $\mathbf{x} + t\mathbf{y}$ has a root if, and only if all the $t_i$s are equal.

Answer (score 3):

The "hence" is referring back to the fact that $f(t) \geq 0$, from the previous sentence. A quadratic polynomial in one variable has a unique extremum, so if it's never negative it can have at most one root.